# Executing Remote Applications With Telnet

Tags: ubuntu, telnet

I need to setup telnet on a Ubuntu server to bypass username/password prompts but start an application on connect for the user to use.

I have installed `telnetd` but now I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't done anything like this in a while I'll just have to give you some guidelines instead that should be close to an outline:

You should be using sshd , generate some certificates and use them to authenticate and hand those to the user, I think there is a method that involves them as credentials and bypasses the login prompt. Regardless of whether you are using telnetd or sshd you can replace the shell that is launched with a program instead, or create a separate user account and include a shell script like bash.rc that launches when the account is logged into regardless if it is local or remote, or it might be the client or both that determines what runs upon login, I think putty can be setup that way.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do with telnet?